# No Result and No Error (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I want to get data from this API [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json](http://https:/facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json) 
 but doesn't get the data and there is no error !!

here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json")
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(findresponse => {
        this.setState({
          data: findresponse.movies
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map((dynamicData, key) => (
          <div>
            <span>{dynamicData.releaseYear}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

any help please

Comment: the code is working. What's the output you're expecting? The only minor issue i can find is `https:/facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json` it should be `https://fa`

Comment: Is this a `react-native` project or a `react` project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use axios instead of fetch.
I encountered the error like yours.
fetch is garbage. It cause a lot of problems.
try axios.

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch('https:/facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
```

your URL is invalid you forgot about `/` - it should be `https://face...`.

other minor issue is that you should use `key` prop:

```
    {this.state.data.map((dynamicData, key) => (
      <div key={key}>
        <span>{dynamicData.releaseYear}</span>
      </div>
    ))}
```

Comment: If you paste `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json` to browser window you will get JSON response. Is there any problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It is working. Can you please let us know what is the error you facing..